# ContextListener is Resulting in Glassfish Error

Tags: java, xml, servlets, netbeans, glassfish

I am trying to run a very basic servlet ContextListener Programme in Netbeans. I have coded it very well but at the last moment while trying to execute it the output tab of the programme is giving me error as shown below..

```
Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.1
GlassFish Server 3.1.1 is running.
In-place deployment at C:\Users\Maunil\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ServletContextListener\build\web
Initializing...
deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Users\Maunil\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ServletContextListener\build\web&name=ServletContextListener&contextroot=/ServletContextListener&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3.1.1 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.awt.HeadlessException. Please see server.log for more details.
C:\Users\Maunil\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ServletContextListener\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

here is my **ContextListener.java** file

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

private ServletContext cont = null;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    this.cont = sce.getServletContext();
    System.out.println("Servlet Initialized....");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Servlet Initialized.......!!!!!!");
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    System.out.println("Servlet Destroyed....!!!");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Servlet Destroyed.......!!!!!!");
    this.cont=null;
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}

}
```

and here is the **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<listener>
    <listener-class>Listener.ContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet.DemoServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DemoServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/DemoServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

there is no syntax error Netbeans has shown. the servlet file is the default file generated by Netbeans IDE.
The point of confusion is... when I try to execute it without the entry of listener to *web.xml* the servlet executes sucesssfully. But after the ContextListener Class entry in .xml file it results in deploymet error.

I want to find out that if there is no error shown by IDE. then where am I doing wrong?? Am I registering the listener class wrongly to the xml file?? or need to configure glassfish..!!!

please guide me through it...

thannx in advance...

Comment: Your `Listener` is throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException`. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: so what this exception is actually doing.... preventing app from deploying by using some privileges??? @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Servlet container startup fails if a listener throws an exception.

Comment: still giving me error even after commenting both of the lines. @SotiriosDelimanolis.. any other sugestions...

Comment: Open up `server.log` and check out the errors. Put log statement in each of your servlet and filter `init` methods. Check if those statements are printed.

Comment: I've tried the same code in windows Xp.. its working perfect.. showing all the JOptionPane.. Why is it so???

Answer (score 0):

The context listener throws a `java.awt.HeadlessException`. This most likely happens because you are trying to use the class `javax.swing.JOptionPane` in a headless environment, which is not allowed.

It is not possible to use most Swing/AWT classes in a headless servlet container because they need a graphical environment to run.

Comment: So what are the things I have to take care of?? little more guidence please.. @David

Comment: Remove all references to `javax.swing.JOptionPane`.

Comment: I've tried the same code in windows Xp.. its working perfect.. showing all the JOptionPane.. Why is it so???

Comment: It will work in a system having a graphical environment (like Ms Windows or X Window) but it will not work in a headless server, where no graphical environment is available (like most Linux servers that are only accessible through ssh).

Comment: i am trying to run it in windows 7. is it having a headless emvironment window???? or am i making some mistakes??

Comment: It could be headless if the server is started with the switch `-Djava.awt.headless=true`. Anyway it is usually considered bad practice to use AWT/Swing classes in a servlet. You should use a logging framework for this kind of messages.